# Change row font on datagridview on mouse over, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to get underline font on datagridview row when mouse is over a row no matter which row is selected.

I get that - a half :)

```
Private Sub aDgv_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles aDgv.MouseMove

    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = aDgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    If hit.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell Then
        aDgv.Rows(hit.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(aDgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Underline)
    End If
End Sub
```

So, when I come over row text in that row becomes underlined (as expected), when I move to next row then those next row becomes underlined but previously don't back to normal font.

What to do that only text in row on which is mouseover become underlined.
How to reset font to normal when mouse goes to other row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To back the normal `Font` just use the `CellMouseLeave` event

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseMove(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseMove
    Dim normalFont = New Font(DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
    If hit.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell Then
        If DataGridView1.Rows(hit.RowIndex).Cells(hit.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString().Trim().Length > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(hit.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Underline)
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows(hit.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = normalFont
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseLeave
    Dim normalFont = New Font(DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
    If (e.ColumnIndex > -1) Then
        If e.RowIndex > -1 Then
            If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString().Trim().Length > 0 Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = normalFont
            Else
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = normalFont
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much! Only is problem in that if I move through row left-right underline is blinking (where is no text or what??). Do you have idea on how to avoid this?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get it work as should be. Have to change String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace to IsNullOrEmpty because my IDE say that IsNullOrWhiteSpace is not member of Strings so I choose closest one: IsNullOrEmpty. Now flickers more than before. What to do?

Comment: This because the previous code is trying to renew the Font even the current `Cell Value` is null or empty.

Comment: it seems that the framework you're using is the older one. `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` was added to .net framework 4.0 or later. i already modified the code.

Comment: I uses 3.5. If you can consider highlighting of row or underline a font with older version than 4 it would be nice.

Comment: Hm, sory for bothering you, I am new in that. Still blinks too much. I installed .framework4, restart and still haven't IsNullOrWhiteSpace in String??

Comment: The .Net 4 is for Visual Studio 2010 and 3.5 is for Visual Studio 2008, but i already modified my answer which is fit to your problem.

Comment: OK, here is still a minor imperfections in functionality but this is very close to final solution. Thank you very much for fighting with problem.